# save and load geographic data in leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I am new to leaflet, I have a requirement of creating a leaflet map where users can add location data. Such data need to be saved somewhere and then restored when the map is loaded again. Rest services need to be implemented to save data and load saved data.
I have already utilized the plugin leaflet.draw to implement part of the requirements; I need your recommendation on the best format and place (file, DB) to save the geographic data.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be interested in Leaflet ["bookmarking" plugins](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#bookmarked-panzoom):

- [Leaflet.Bookmarks](https://github.com/w8r/Leaflet.Bookmarks): Highly customizable Leaflet plugin for user-generated bookmarks, stored locally or on the server. [Demo](http://w8r.github.io/Leaflet.Bookmarks/).
- [Leaflet-Storage](https://github.com/umap-project/Leaflet.Storage): Manage map and features with Leaflet and expose them for backend storage with an API. [Demo](http://umap.fluv.io/).